# Unable to deploy application on AWS pipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      php: 7.3
  pre_build: # commands to be run before build
    commands:

      - aws --version


  build:
    commands:
      - echo Build started on `date`
      - echo installing composer..
      - composer install
      - echo creating .env file..
      - cp .env.example .env
      - echo generating app key
      - php artisan key:generate
      - echo Building the Docker image...

  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo Build completed on `date`
```

This is my build specs file used to create pipeline on was.once  I made change on git hub it will succeed fully propagate to the build section .But When it comes to the Deployment stage I get the following error.

```
The action failed because either the artifact or the Amazon S3 bucket could not be found. Name of artifact bucket: codepipeline-us-east-1-245934183698. Verify that this bucket exists. If it exists, check the life cycle policy, then try releasing a change.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to run:

```
aws codepipeline get-pipeline --name <YOUR_PIPELINE_NAME> --profile <PROFILE> --region <REGION>
```

Check the name of the S3 bucket in the output under `artifactStore` and see if the  S3 bucket exists on the region of your pipeline and the account.

Comment: I checked the bucket comes under the artifactstore and it. is available on the S3